# how to update a tag column based on multiple values against an ID column

Tags: sql

WOuld like to check on how I can query the following scenario?

[image: Customer Table]

In this scenario, customer CU_001 has multiple products and statuses. I need to tag CU_001 as active if one of the products has "Paying" Status or "Paying-Installment". However, if the customer has other status except the two, it will be tag as Inactive. Like CU_002, its has only one product and should be tagged as inactive.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: [Images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527) should not be used for textual data.

Comment: Since SQL includes data definition, a [mcve] for an [SQL question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/90527) should include [DDL](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statements for sample tables (rather than an ad hoc table specification) and [DML](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) statements for sample data (rather than a dump or ad hoc format). Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves.

Comment: What does it mean to "tag a customer"?

Comment: Related to "[MYSQL GROUP BY with different valies in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56824818/90527)".

Answer (score 1):

so you could use a query like below to give you all customers which need to be tagged

```
Select CustomerID
from customertable
where status in ('paying', 'paying-installment')
```

if the tag column is in the same table then

```
update ct
set tag=case when c.customerid is not null then 'active' else 'inactive' end
from
customertable ct
left join 
(
Select CustomerID
    from customertable
    where status in ('paying', 'paying-installment')
) c
on ct.CustomerID=c.CustomerID
```

if this is another table then simple replace

```
from
customertable ct
```

with

```
from
<othertablename> ct
```

Comment: hi, DhruvJoshi. here's my query  but it doesnt seem to work: SELECT customerid
FROM custtable
where stats in ('1','2','3','4','5')
update ct
set tag=case when c.customerid is not null then 'active' else 'inactive' end
from
custtable ct
left join
(
Select customerid
    from custtable
    where stats in ('1','2','3','4','5')
    ) c
on ct.customerid=c.customerid

Answer (score 0):

If this is just something you want to view, adhoc, then the below will work, as it does not set anything in the tables:

This code will add a column with the status for every line:

```
SELECT 
    [Customer ID],
    Product,
    Status,
    CASE Status
        WHEN 'Paying'
                THEN
                    'Active'
        WHEN 'Paying-Installment'
                THEN
                    'Active'
        ELSE
            'Inactive'
        END AS Active
FROM customerTable
```

This code will add a column with the status but only show the customer and the status:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    [Customer ID],
    CASE Status
        WHEN 'Paying'
                THEN
                    'Active'
        WHEN 'Paying-Installment'
                THEN
                    'Active'
        ELSE
            'Inactive'
        END AS Active
FROM customerTable
```

The difference between the two is what columns are shown, and the DISTINCT command.

Comment: wow, thanks a lot for this! 2nd script works fine for me!

Comment: Just minor improvement use `CASE Status WHEN 'Paying' THEN 'Active' WHEN 'Paying-Installment' THEN 'Active' ELSE 'Inactive' END AS Active` instead of `CASE WHEN Status = 'Paying' THEN 'Active' WHEN Status = 'Paying-Installment' THEN 'Active' ELSE 'Inactive' END AS Active`.

Comment: Thanks, I edited to show the your suggestion. I like the simpler script.

Comment: Hi, the query is returning two statuses if there are other status besides paying, paying installment. There are several status in the system. But in my scenario - i need to tag the customers active if the they have products with any of  these statuses , 1,2,3,4 and 5. Say the customer has 10 products but only one products has the status of 1,2,3,4 and 5 then it should be active. If they dont have any of these, then inactive.